# Postgres - How to SUM every x amount of rows of a window function column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I created a column using a window function called "avg_rev" that gives the average amount of revenue by sales region for the last 7 days using:

```
AVG(rev) OVER (PARTITION BY sales_region ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg_rev
```

I want to add up the average revenues returned for each sales region **by day**. So for the following table:

```
date     | sales_region | rev    | avg_rev
---------|--------------|--------|---------
01-23-18 | US East      | 192643 | 187463
01-23-18 | US South     | 89734  | 90245
01-23-18 | US West      | 254867 | 270974
01-24-18 | US East      | 168903 | 189245
01-24-18 | US South     | 93127  | 90621
01-24-18 | US West      | 252075 | 269874
```

I want another column showing the total average revenue for each day by summing the last 3 rows (or any other way to get the same result) in order to have the following table:

```
date     | sales_region | rev    | avg_rev | total_avg
---------|--------------|--------|---------|-----------
01-23-18 | US East      | 192643 | 187463  | 548682
01-23-18 | US South     | 89734  | 90245   | 548682
01-23-18 | US West      | 254867 | 270974  | 548682
01-24-18 | US East      | 168903 | 189245  | 550740
01-24-18 | US South     | 93127  | 91621   | 550740
01-24-18 | US West      | 252075 | 269874  | 550740
```

As you can see the total average revenue stays consistent because they should have the same sum for each day.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate the value with `SUM` and include all the other columns selected in `group by`.

```
select date,sales_region,rev
,AVG(rev) OVER (PARTITION BY sales_region ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg_rev
,SUM(AVG(rev)) OVER (PARTITION BY sales_region ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg_sum
from tbl
group by date,sales_region,rev
```

Answer (score 1):

If I really had to guess what you want, it would look like:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(avg_rev_7day) OVER (PARTITION BY date)
FROM (SELECT AVG(rev) OVER (PARTITION BY sales_region
                            ORDER BY date
                            ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECENDING
                           ) AS avg_rev_7day,

      . . .
     ) t
```

Note:

- ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is really *8* days and not *7* days.  I assume you want 7 rows.
- The window clause (the `ROWS` part) really needs an `ORDER BY`.
- For what you want to do, I think nested subqueries are best.